# How to open a new React app when redirected?

Tags: reactjs, http

A have a React app that handles the login form and a separate React app that shows a dashboard. I want the browser to load the dashboard app when the login is successful.

I've attempted to do this by sending a redirect response from my server (status code: 302, Location header attached). The server responds to this request correctly and sends the `index.html` file of the dashboard app to the client.

The browser receives this file successfully, but does not load it (URL does not change either).

Here're the response headers to the received `index.html` file:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 624
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Sun, 16 Oct 2022 09:40:25 GMT
Date: Sun, 16 Oct 2022 16:38:37 GMT
```

My question is: how can I make the browser replace all currently used React code with the one that's coming from redirect? Do I need to set additional headers for that? Or should this be handled in frontend somehow?

Comment: Do both this apps run on the same url?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, both apps use the same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement it by doing these three things:

- In the login app, once I receive a response with the dashboard `index.html` file, I reset URL to the root path with
  `window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/"`.
  This automatically loads this newly received `index.html` file.
- On my server, I make sure to check if the request contains the correct cookie. If it does, I return the dashboard app files. Otherwise, I return the login app files.

  Whenever the browser sends a request for some internal React path (e.g. `localhost:3001/article/1`), I return the correct `index.html` file instead. Once the `index.html` is loaded, the app will automatically open the right page (I'm using react-router here).

  This takes care of the situations when I want to open a link to a specific route within my React app.
- Once login is successful and I get redirected to the dashboard app, if I click on the back button, the browser opens the previously replaced login app again. This happens because all responses from the server are cashed automatically.

  To avoid this, I set the `Cache-Control` header to `no-store` for my responses on the server. This way, I can click on the back button and get redirected to the root dashboard page instead (or some other path that is handled by the dashboard app).

  The `no-cache` header is only required when the login app is served. The dashboard app can be cached. I'm not sure how this will change when I'll implement the logout functionality.

This pretty much allows for the seamless transition between the two React apps I'm serving. The `no-cache` condition seems a bit harsh, but at this moment I don't see any way around it.